# is there a way to allow developers to edit code but stopping them from downloading or cloning the code on

Tags: git, ide, gitlab

I need an IDE, repository or anything that works really....

Where I am in an environment where me and my developers can work on the same project, edit files but **I don't want the developers** being able to download the code or clone the code via Git for intellectual property purposes.

Comment: What i am looking for is an option where the developpers cant download the code i  the first place. I woulf want them to edit code online but I dont want them to have a copy of the code.

Comment: If they can edit the code online, they can copy and paste it to a text file if they really want. This expectation seems unrealistic...

Comment: If you don't trust your developers for IP purposes,**YOU SHOULDN'T HIRE THEM**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to allow editing, but without the editors having a copy of the code? You could investigate remote desktop solutions, your editors would then connect to a remote desktop server and do all their work on that server. The source code would not be externally accessible, only via the remote desktop connection.

Bear in mind though, that the editor could (most likely) still copy and paste the code onto their local machine, as most remote desktop clients auto share the clipboard.

Comment: Any self-respecting programmer would refuse to work under such conditions.

Answer (score 2):

That the whole point of source control (doesn't matter if its git in this manner). To share and to allow multiple users to work on the code simultaneously.

What you are asking is to disallow users to share code in any way,

> I don't want the developers being able to download the code or clone the code via Git for intellectual property purposes.

When someone download the code you can't control what he does with it once its downloaded. It's not clear what you want. You want to work with git but to restrict users form abusing your code?

Once the code is downloaded you can only restrict who can push code back to the server, not more than that.